# numba.vectorize ufunc does not support timedelta64

Tags: numpy, vectorization, numba, timedelta

Example code with a NumPy ufunc:

```
import numpy as np

nums = np.array([1, 2, 3])
times = nums.astype('timedelta64[ns]')

np.less(nums, 2)
np.less(nums, np.timedelta64(2))
```

Both of those give the same result:

```
array([ True, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

Now I want to do something similar with Numba:

```
import numba

@numba.vectorize(nopython=True)
def myless(a, b):
    return a < b

myless(nums, 2)
myless(times, np.timedelta64(2)) # fails
```

The first gives the correct result, but the second fails:

> TypeError: ufunc 'myless' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

What's wrong?  How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a hint in the Numba 0.17 release notes (which by now is quite an old version):

> Issue #917: Allow vectorizing with datetime64 and timedelta64 in the signature (only with unit-less values, though, because of a Numpy limitation).

which leads to this [comment](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/917#issuecomment-69011988):

> it seems numpy won't less us call ufuncs with non-unitless datetimes and timedeltas, so we're cooked [...]

So apparently you cannot ever use Numba vectorized ufuncs with NumPy timedelta64 in nopython mode, unless the timedelta64 has no units specified (in my example the array type had `[ns]` for nanoseconds, and even adding the units to the scalar doesn't help).

Answer (score 0):

It's only a workaround, but you can always zero-copy view your timedeltas as integers (and vice-versa)

```
In [80]: i8 = np.dtype('int64')

In [81]: myless(times.view(i8), np.timedelta64(2).view(i8))
Out[81]: array([ True, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: Yeah, though that makes it awkward at the call site.  Not good, because wrappers for ufuncs take away all the ufunc magic.  You can't really hide the hack anywhere as far as I can tell.  Plus, you'll still need a copy if the units differ (e.g. comparing seconds with nanoseconds).